# Devuan/Debian Linux USB installation issue

Tags: linux, debian, installation, iso-image, devuan

I am trying to install [Devuan Linux](https://devuan.org/) (a Debian derivative), but I get stuck at the beginning.

- Downloaded the DVD ISO: [devuan_ascii_2.0.0_amd64_dvd-1.iso](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/devuan/devuan_ascii/installer-iso/devuan_ascii_2.0.0_amd64_dvd-1.iso)
- Decompressed the ISO file on a USB key with [Rufus 3.1](https://rufus.akeo.ie/); everything seems to be fine, I get the complete directory hierarchy.
- The laptop (Dell Precision 7720) has an empty main SSD drive.
- I boot the laptop from the USB key.

Note: when decompressing the ISO file on the USB key with the Rufus tool, in the  "Create a bootable disk using" dialog, I tried both ISO and DD modes, with the same result.

After a few questions, I get to this menu:

```
Devuan installer main menu

Choose the next step in the install process:

Choose language  
Access software for a blind person using a braille display  
Configure the speech synthesizer voice  
Configure the keyboard  
Detect an mount CD-ROM  
Load installer components from CD  
Change debconf priority  
Check the CD-ROM(s) integrity  
Save debug logs  
Execute a shell  
Abort the installation
```

When I get to the point "Detect an mount CD-ROM", I tried both specifying I have no CD-ROM, and trying to cheat hoping it would have taken the USB key as a CD-ROM. None worked.

When selecting "Load installer components from CD", I get the error "No common CD-ROM drive was detected".

What am I doing wrong? At the beginning the installation from USB is fine, but then it seems the only option is to continue from a CD-ROM (for which I have no drive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting an expert mode installation, the installer accepts the USB key as a CD.
When installing in normal mode, the USB key is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the **[devuan_ascii_2.0.0_amd64_netinst.iso](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/devuan/devuan_ascii/installer-iso/devuan_ascii_2.0.0_amd64_netinst.iso)**.

The image you have downloaded is for use by a DVD. **Netinst** is a network install and does not care whether you are installing from DVD, CD, or USB, you just need working internet.

From what I see this is your only option, assuming you have internet.

Comment: From where I am now, I cannot install through the network.

Comment: I tried to install from the network, but I got the same result.

Comment: Using the netinst.iso? That shouldn't happen. Unless your BIOS is misconfigured in some way. And also, if in expert mode it accepts your USB, why not install via expert mode?

Comment: Yes. With both netinst and DVD image, I got what you can see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1335336/linux-installation-error-related-to-file-system).