# Linux installation error related to file system

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, uefi, formatting

Installing Devuan Linux (Debian derivative), I get this error message:

> The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed.

During the installation, I did not specify to create a vfat file system (the SSD was empty), and I did not specify to create the EFI partition under boot/.

This is the SSD required partitioning structure:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 - 1.0 TB Unknown

  1 MB  FREE SPACE
 98 MB  ESP    EFI
 50 GB  ext4   /      /
 10 GB  ext4   var    /var
 68 GB  swap   swap   swap
  4 GB  ext4   tmp    /tmp
 50 GB  ext4   opt    /opt
500 GB  btrfs  home   /home
342 GB  FREE SPACE
```

I have not been able to get rid of the first 1 MB block of free space, but that should not be the problem.

The system is configured to use UEFI.

- Do I need to add a /boot partition?
- Do I need to add an ESP partition?
- Is a 98 MB size EFI partition enough?

  - Does its size depend on the number of operating systems installed?

How can I fix my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming **UEFI/GPT** in the answers below.*

## 1 MiB Free Space

There are [both](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Creating_the_partitions) fail safes and alignment reasons for that 1 MiB (also at the end of disks), so it should not be a problem.

## `/boot`

You probably do not need a `/boot` partition. There are some specific [cases](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#.2Fboot).

## `ESP`

Under the assumption above, you do need an [ESP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition), and you do have one. **ESP** stands for **E**FI **S**ystem **P**artition and **UEFI** (the **U** is dropped in some cases) stands for **U**nified **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface.

## `ESP` Size

98 MB is most likely too small (uncertain if this is causing the error message though). [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#diskpartitionrules) says 100 MiB is the minimum, though a good [recommendation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) is 550 MiB.

## Other Considerations

I have never installed Devuan and can therefore not answer about that specific error message. It could be a bug in the installer software. I have come across bugs that I suspect was related to it being a NVMe disk.

I do recommend increasing the size as described above. In addition, you only **need** ESP (`/boot/efi`) (possibly `/boot` instead) and root (`/`) partitions, but the others are fine. Also make sure that ESP has `vfat` (preferably `FAT32`) filesystem and the `esp` (or `boot, esp`) flag (sometimes referred to as `EFI System` or `EF00`). You can keep the other partitions as long as you do not try to have several ESP. Also the 68 GB swap seems excessive.

## UEFI/MBR

My initial assumption might have been incorrect. If you use `MBR` ("`dos`") partition layout, then there is in some tools (e.g., `fdisk`) a `bootable` flag that has to be set, in `fdisk` it is shown as an asterix `*` in the `Boot` column when printing the table on screen. See this related *Stack Exchange: Unix & Linux* [question](https://superuser.com/a/764871/908619).

However, it is usually recommended to use GPT layout with UEFI, please see the [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#GPT_or_MBR) and [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR).

Comment: I defined a `/boot/efi` partition as the first one, 600MB, FAT32. I cannot set the bootable flag to on. Is it fine?

Comment: Confirming to write the changes to disk, I get: "No EFI partition was found". I will follow your suggestion, and restart from the automatic partitioning.

Comment: I selected automatic partitioning, the EFI partition was set as bootable, I deleted the ext4 /home partition, I added a new ext4 /opt and a btrfs /home partition. Everything seems to be going on well now...

Comment: I had the EFI partition with a 'b', which I guess should mean "bootable".